# Java Second static method not executing

Tags: java, methods

I can't figure out why the second method does not execute. It compiles and accepts input, but after that nothing happens.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) { 
        String hoursOfWorkString, costOfMaterialsString, nameOfProductString;

        nameOfProductString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name of the product. ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
        hoursOfWorkString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of hours worked. ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

        double hoursOfWork = Double.parseDouble(hoursOfWorkString);

        costOfMaterialsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the cost of the product. ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);           
        double costOfMaterials = Double.parseDouble(costOfMaterialsString);
    }



    public static void CalulatePrice(double costOfMaterials, double hoursOfWork, String nameOfProductString) {
        double salePercentage = 0.75, shipping = 6, markup = 14, retailPrice;

        retailPrice = salePercentage * (costOfMaterials + (markup * hoursOfWork)) + shipping; 

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("The retaill price of the %. product is $ %.02f.", nameOfProductString, retailPrice));
    }
}
```

Update: I used the example and fixed a few other errors and it runs.  After reading the comment, I did not think it would work. I just knew that something was off with my code.

Thank you everyone for your inputs.

Comment: It may be because you don't call it?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you think it would execute.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have defined your function, but you haven't called it. Insert a call at the end of your `main` method, like

```
double costOfMaterials = Double.parseDouble(costOfMaterialsString);
// Here...
CalulatePrice(costOfMaterials, hoursOfWork, nameOfProductString);
```

**Also**, I think you *meant* **calculate**. And, ***please*** follow Java naming conventions, it should be something like `calculatePrice`.